# Using WallTime.js for js timezone conversion but getting an error

Tags: javascript, timezone, commonjs, walltime-js

I have a client that is on the west coast, but wants to see information based on east coast time (America/New York).

I am trying to use the WallTime library: https://github.com/sproutsocial/walltime-js

```
define(function(require) {

var _ = require('underscore'),
    Backbone = require('backbone'),
    WallTime = require('walltime');
require('backbone.relational');
require('walltime-data');


var DateRange = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    initialize: function(opts) {

        var self = this,
            type = (opts && opts.type) || "today";

        if(type == "custom") {
            var undef = _.isUndefined(opts.start) && _.isUndefined(opts.end);

            if(undef)
                throw "'start' and/or 'end' date not present in options for type: custom";
        }

        function getNycDate(date){
            var someUTCDate = new Date(date.getTime()),
            nycWallTime = WallTime.UTCToWallTime(someUTCDate, "America/New_York");
            return nycWallTime;
        }

        function setup() {
            var now = getNycDate(new Date());
        }
     }
   }
}
```

When trying to calculate the walltime I am getting the following error:
    Uncaught Error: Must call init with rules and zones before setting time zone

Comment: I don't think you are loading `walltime-data.js` properly.  You appear to be using RequireJS.  Did you set up `walltime` and `walltime-data` as modules?  Did you set `walltime-data` as a dependency for `wall-time`?  See the [RequireJS docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#funcmodule).

Comment: @Matt Johnson: these `require`s are CommonJS modules, not AMD format supported by `RequireJS` (comparison here: http://blog.millermedeiros.com/amd-is-better-for-the-web-than-commonjs-modules/ )

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you attempt to initialize WallTime before loading your Timezone data. Reorder your require statements and/or require timezone data first.

Source: I'm a SproutSocial developer.